# IBM Worklight filter HTTP Adapter response

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I was checking out IBM worklight and used HTTP Adapters. In my Rest response I get so many details. I want to filter the records like send the specific nodes to the app as response.

For example

[Google distance API URL](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver%20BC%7CSeattle&destinations=San%20Francisco%7CVictoria%20BC&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&sensor=false)

It returns so many data which I don't need and I want to send filtered records to app like,

distance: {
        "value": 1734542,
        "text": "1 735 km"
      }

Is it possible anyway in the Worklight HTTP Adapters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure, you can use JavaScript to filter data and create only response that you need. In case you use XML based web-service you can even use XSLT transformation.
In case your webservice returns JSON like the one you've provided, use something like:

```
var backendResponse = WL.Server.invokeHttp(....);
var adapterResponse = {
      distanceValue : backendResponse.somePropertyDescribingDistanceValue,
      distanceText : backendResponse.someOtherPropertyDescribingDistanceText
};

return adapterResponse;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use xsl filter in adapter for filtering the contents of the response as well.